# Angular how to print when value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure what to use here but I'm trying to switch item.departments when the value changes.  So, basically, I want to list employees within item.department and when the item.department changes, I want to print that item.department and continue on until item.department changes again.  Is there a way to do that in Angular?

Like this...

```
Department A
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3

Department B
Name 1

Department C
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4


<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 col-3xl-3 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text card-subtle-text ">{{item.DEPARTMENT}}</p>
        <h3 class="card-title card-heading card-title-mark">{{item.NAME}}</h3>
        <span class="card-support">{{item.JOBTITLE}}</span>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.CAMPUS}}</p>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <p class="card-text"><strong>Phone: </strong>{{item.PHONE}}</p>
        <p class="card-text"><strong>Email: </strong><span ng-bind-html="item.EMAIL"></span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use an observable.

Comment: When what value changes? The short answer is likely: AngularJS displays HTML based on data models. If you change the data model, the HTML changes. If you could expand your question, show a sample of the data source etc. That would help people give you a more direct answer

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  I used an ng-if statement to look at different values and when they changed.  Sorry, I can't show you the data.  That's the bad thing about working for a University/College.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I used an ng-if statement to look at different values and when they changed. Sorry, I can't show you the data. That's the bad thing about working for a University/College.

I used the "ng-if={item.DEPARTMENT}" to create a divider between the different departments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).